# FastAPI query parameter using Pydantic model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a Pydantic model as below

```
class Student(BaseModel):
    name:str
    age:int
```

With this setup, I wish to get the OpenAPI schema as following,

[image]

So, how can I use the Pydantic model to get the from query parameter in FastAPI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


@app.get("/")
def read_root(student: Student = Depends()):
    return {"name": student.name, "age": student.age}
```

Also, note that the query parameters are usually "*optional*" fields and if you wish to make them optional, use **`Optional`** type hint as,

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: Optional[int]


@app.get("/")
def read_root(student: Student = Depends()):
    return {"name": student.name, "age": student.age}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a question what if i don't specify ```student: Student = Depends()``` and just use ```def read_root(student: Student):```? Why do we need to use ```Depends``` here?

Comment: IIRC, you won't get the schema representation *"in this case"*. Checkout more about [`Depends(...)`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/)

Comment: how to add a description to the name and age field?

Comment: question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75998227/fastapi-does-not-allow-pydantic-model-for-query-variable-how-to-fix-it