# Is it possible to map a pydantic __root__ field to a FastAPI query parameter?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

My main goal is to define validation rules for name tags only once and reuse it later in diffrent places (e.g. query params, resource path).
For that, i try to use pydantic model with `__root__` as fastapi query/path parameter.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468402/query-parameters-from-pydantic-model) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580885/fastapi-query-parameter-using-pydantic-model) looks like answer but unfortunately for some reason non primitives fields in query model treats as body fields

The base code:

```py
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


app = FastAPI()


class TagName(BaseModel):
    __root__: str = Field(example='aot', max_length=128, min_length=3)
```

Then i try to use the following ways to tell fastapi treat `TagName` as query param:

### Using Query

```py
@app.patch('/')
async def change_tag_by_name(
    query: Annotated[TagName, Query()],
):
    ...
```

AssertionError: Param: query can only be a request body, using Body()`

### Using Depends with simple class

```py
class ChangeTagByNameQuery:
    def __init__(self, tag: TagName):
        self.tag = tag

@app.patch('/')
async def change_tag_by_name(
    query: Annotated[TagName, Depends(ChangeTagByNameQuery)],
):
    ...
```

It successfully runs, but fastapi just includes `ChangeTagByNameQuery.name` into the body schema:

```json
...
"paths":{
    "/":{
      "patch":{
        "summary":"Change Tag By Name",
        "operationId":"change_tag_by_name__patch",
        "requestBody":{
          "content":{
            "application/json":{
              "schema":{
                "$ref":"#/components/schemas/TagName"
              }
            }
          },
          "required":true
        },
...
```

The main

Comment: Your code is incomplete and not reproducible. Please provide an actual [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including some expected output and the actual output or full error message. A MRE for your use case should not take up more than 20-30 lines of code including all relevant imports. You can use the [_Edit_](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76295052/edit) function to improve your question.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Ok, i provided MRE

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76137214/17865804)?